# RecycleView dentro de un ExpandibleListView

Tags: android, recyclerview

como estan?

Estoy trabajando en una app de Android en Java que necesito usar un ExpadibleListView que contenga dentro un RecycleView

Esto es una lista de pedidos, que al hacer click sobre uno, se expanda y muestre los items de ese pedido.

Pero lo que me está pasando es que hacer click sobre alguno de los pedidos, lo que se expande muestra  la información de los items. n cantidad de veces segun los items que haya, es decir, si tengo 3 items, va a mostrar 3 veces cada item por ej:
Pedido1 contiene item1 e item 2 y el pedido2 tiene item3, item4 e item5 lo muestra de esta manera:

Pedido1

- item1
- item2
- item1
- item2

Pedido2

- Item3
  -Item4
  -Item5
- Item3
  -Item4
  -Item5
- Item3
  -Item4
  -Item5

el codigo que tengo es el siguiente
fragment_home.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:id="@+id/expandableListView_pedidos"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

pedido_list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="nro: "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pedido_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fecha_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="21/08/2023 18:12"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#B526CD"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/estado_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="REALIZADO"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$  "
                android:textSize="25sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/importe_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10.550,00"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

pedido_item_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lista_items_pedido"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:text="Observaciones"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F1EFEF"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:text="estamos haciendo una prueba de observacion"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

y pedido_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descripcion_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Atenolol"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/importe_pedido"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2000.00"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

tambien estan los xml de transicion del expandibleListView:
slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="9000" />
</set>
```

y slide_up.xml

```
<!-- res/anim/slide_up.xml -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

y para java:
'''

```
public class Pedido {

    private Long idPedido;
    private String fecha;
    private String estado;
    private Double importe;
    List<PedidoItem> items;

    public Pedido() {
    }

    public Pedido(Long idPedido, String fecha, String estado, Double importe, List<PedidoItem> items) {
        this.idPedido = idPedido;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.importe = importe;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Long getIdPedido() {
        return idPedido;
    }

    public void setIdPedido(Long idPedido) {
        this.idPedido = idPedido;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Double getImporte() {
        return importe;
    }

    public void setImporte(Double importe) {
        this.importe = importe;
    }

    public List<PedidoItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<PedidoItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

'''

PedidoItem:

```
public class PedidoItem {

    private Integer id;
    private String descripcion;
    private Double precio;

    public PedidoItem() {
    }

    public PedidoItem(Integer id, String descripcion, Double precio) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(Double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
```

Home_fragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    private ExpandiblePedidoAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private List<Pedido> pedidosList;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        pedidosList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PedidoItem> items1 = new ArrayList<>();
        items1.add(new PedidoItem(1, "Clonazepam", 1000.00));
        items1.add(new PedidoItem(2, "Alplax", 1500.00));
        pedidosList.add(new Pedido(123L, "24/07/2023 22:25" , "EN PROCESO", 2500.00, items1));

        List<PedidoItem> items2 = new ArrayList<>();
        items2.add(new PedidoItem(1, "Atenolol", 1000.00));
        items2.add(new PedidoItem(2, "Aspirinetas", 1300.00));
        items2.add(new PedidoItem(3, "Empecid", 1500.00));
        pedidosList.add(new Pedido(534L,"24/07/2023 21:35" , "REALIZADO", 3800.00, items2));

        List<PedidoItem> items3 = new ArrayList<>();
        items3.add(new PedidoItem(1, "Amoxidal", 1000.00));
        items3.add(new PedidoItem(2, "Paratrobil", 1300.00));
        items3.add(new PedidoItem(3, "Curitas", 1500.00));
        pedidosList.add(new Pedido(558L,"24/07/2023 21:09" , "EN DEMORA", 3800.00, items3));

        List<PedidoItem> items4 = new ArrayList<>();
        items4.add(new PedidoItem(1, "Atenolol", 1000.00));
        items4.add(new PedidoItem(2, "Paratrobil", 1300.00));
        items4.add(new PedidoItem(3, "Alplax", 1500.00));
        pedidosList.add(new Pedido(254L, "24/07/2023 21:25" , "CANCELADO", 3800.00, items4));

        // Inicializa el ExpandableListView y el adaptador
        expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView_pedidos);
        expandableListAdapter = new ExpandiblePedidoAdapter(this.getContext(), pedidosList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);



        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                // Expandir el grupo actual y aplicar animación al hijo
                View childView = expandableListAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition, 0, false, null, null);
                animateExpand(childView, true);
            }
        });

        // Agregar un Listener para detectar los cambios en la contracción del grupo
        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                // Contraer el grupo actual y aplicar animación al hijo
                View childView = expandableListAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition, 0, false, null, null);
                animateExpand(childView, false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void animateExpand(View view, boolean expand) {
        Animation animation;
        if (expand) {
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
        } else {
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
        }
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

ExpandiblePedidoAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandiblePedidoAdapter  extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Pedido> pedidosList;

    public ExpandiblePedidoAdapter(Context context, List<Pedido> pedidosList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pedidosList = pedidosList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return pedidosList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return pedidosList.get(groupPosition).getItems().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return pedidosList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return pedidosList.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_list_group, null);
        }
        TextView pedidoIdTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.pedido_id);
        TextView fechaPedidoTv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_id);
        TextView importePedidoTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.importe_id);
        TextView estadoTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.estado_id);
        Pedido pedido = (Pedido) getGroup(groupPosition);
        pedidoIdTv.setText(pedido.getIdPedido().toString());
        //fechaPedidoTv.setText(UtilsTools.traerFechaddMMyyyyhhmm(pedido.getFechaPedido()));
        fechaPedidoTv.setText(pedido.getFecha());
        importePedidoTV.setText(pedido.getImporte().toString());
        estadoTV.setText(pedido.getEstado());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_item_list, null);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_items_pedido);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            childViewHolder.recyclerView = recyclerView;
            convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);
        } else {
            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        List<PedidoItem> items = pedidosList.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        if (childViewHolder.adapter == null) {
            childViewHolder.adapter = new ItemPedidosAdapter(context, items);
            childViewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(childViewHolder.adapter);
        } else {
            childViewHolder.adapter.setItems(items);
            childViewHolder.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ChildViewHolder {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ItemPedidosAdapter adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }


}
```

ItemPedidoAdapter.java

```
public class ItemPedidosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemPedidosAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<PedidoItem> items;

    public ItemPedidosAdapter(Context context, List<PedidoItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pedido_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PedidoItem item = items.get(position);
        //holder.textViewIdItem.setText(item.getId().toString());
        holder.textViewDescripcion.setText(item.getDescripcion());
        holder.textViewImporteItem.setText("$" + item.getPrecio());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //TextView textViewIdItem;
        TextView textViewDescripcion;
        TextView textViewImporteItem;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //textViewIdItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
            textViewDescripcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_item);
            textViewImporteItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.importe_pedido);
        }
    }

    public List<PedidoItem> getItems() {
        return items;
}
    public void setItems(List<PedidoItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

perdon si mandé demasiado código, se que en algun momento el adapter o el recycleView se esta instanciando cada vez que toma el list de items, pero no se donde.
me podrán dar una mano?

gracias!